# Foreign key appears twice in generated query using association and include

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to get all users associated to timeoff. This is the Timeoff model:

```
"use strict";
const { Model } = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Timeoff extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      Timeoff.belongsTo(models.User, {
        foreignKey: "userId",
      });
    }
  }
  Timeoff.init(
    {
      userId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      date:DataTypes.DATEONLY
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "Timeoff",
    }
  );

  Timeoff.findUsers = async (startDate, endDate) => {
    try {
      const object = await sequelize.models.Timeoff.findAll({
        include: {
          model: sequelize.models.User,
        },
      });

      return Promise.resolve(object);
    } catch (error) {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  };

  return Timeoff;
};
```

The query complains: `error: column Timeoff.UserId does not exist`

The generated query has the foreign key twice, once as 'userId' and again as 'UserId' capitalized:

```
SELECT 
  "Timeoff"."id", 
  "Timeoff"."userId", 
...
  "Timeoff"."UserId",
```

Any idea what causes this and how to have only the foreign key 'userId' in the generated query? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

This in the other model, User, makes it fail:

```
static associate(models) {
  User.hasMany(models.Timeoff);
}
```

But this in User model makes it succeed:

```
static associate(models) {
  User.hasMany(models.Timeoff, {
    as: "timeoffs",
    foreignKey: "userId",
  });
```

As to why, I do not know yet.

Answer (score 0):

You should indicate the same `foreignKey` options in both paired associations in order to make working associations in queries because Sequelize takes into account both associations.